# Kill a Process by Looking up the Port being used by it from a .BAT

Tags: windows, batch-file, process, kill-process

In Windows what can look for port 8080 and try to kill the process it is using through a .BAT file?

Comment: I can get you part of the way there... from the command prompt use the command 'netstat -a -n -o' and you will see a list of processes and which ports they are listening on (as well as ip and whether they are connected to another IP or not..) Invaluable. There'll almost certainly be nicer switches to refine the results, but I can't remember them off hand... Hopefully someone can build on this?

Comment: In linux you can. if you install cygwin you would be able to in bat aswell

Comment: @Dani, Mike: Cygwin is a huge dependency and not required to solve this problem.  If you've already got it, though, use it - linux command line tools are much better.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Here's a command to get you started:

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :8080') DO @ECHO TaskKill.exe /PID %%P
```

When you're confident in your batch file, remove `@ECHO`.

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :8080') DO TaskKill.exe /PID %%P
```

Note that you might need to change this slightly for different OS's.  For example, on Windows 7 you might need `tokens=5` instead of `tokens=4`.

**How this works**

```
FOR /F ... %variable IN ('command') DO otherCommand %variable...
```

This lets you execute `command`, and loop over its output.  Each line will be stuffed into `%variable`, and can be expanded out in `otherCommand` as many times as you like, wherever you like.  `%variable` in actual use can only have a single-letter name, e.g. `%V`.

```
"tokens=4 delims= "
```

This lets you split up each line by whitespace, and take the 4th chunk in that line, and stuffs it into `%variable` (in our case, `%%P`).  `delims` looks empty, but that extra space is actually significant.

```
netstat -a -n -o
```

Just run it and find out.  According to the command line help, it "Displays all connections and listening ports.", "Displays addresses and port numbers in numerical form.", and "Displays the owning process ID associated with each connection.".  I just used these options since someone else suggested it, and it happened to work :)

```
^|
```

This takes the output of the first command or program (`netstat`) and passes it onto a second command program (`findstr`).  If you were using this directly on the command line, instead of inside a command string, you would use `|` instead of `^|`.

```
findstr :8080
```

This filters any output that is passed into it, returning only lines that contain `:8080`.

```
TaskKill.exe /PID <value>
```

This kills a running task, using the process ID.

```
%%P instead of %P
```

This is required in batch files.  If you did this on the command prompt, you would use `%P` instead.

Comment: You may need to play with tokens, delims, etc.  Check `HELP FOR` on the command line to see a lot of other options that `FOR` will give you, and check `netstat -?`, `findstr /?`, and `TaskKill /?` for even more help.

Comment: I will try it out and get back to you.

Comment: FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :8080') DO TaskKill.exe /F /PID %%P

Comment: @Mike: Weird.  tokens=4 works for me and 5 doesn't.  I am thinking there is system or environment dependent stuff going on here, so be sure to watch out for that.

Comment: This is great. `tokens=4` is Windows XP I think and `tokens=5` Windows 7. Also a good idea to `/F` force the kill.

Comment: you helped solving my problem too, thanks for really taking time to describe each of the step. two thumbs up.

Comment: For windows server 2008, you should set tokens=5 to get the PID

Comment: Hi, What is the token to be set for Windows 8 and Windows 8.1?

Comment: For Windows 8, tokens=5

Comment: I had to run two commands : FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :8080') DO TaskKill.exe /PID %P /t /f    and FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :8080') DO TaskKill.exe /PID %P /f     The parent were never really killed

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham when I am trying this command I am getting an error - 'netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :8080' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Here is what i have tried to troubleshoot:   (1) The command netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :8080 gives the result       (2) I have tried replacing single quote ' with a backtick ` , but that doesn't seem to work as well. Could you please tell me what could be the problem. I am running the command on windows 7 cmd.exe

Comment: @nishantv: Back tick isn't a Windows thing, so it of course won't work. Try typing `netstat` and try typing `findstr` separately. If either of them don't work you've found your culprit. Either way, I have no idea why you don't have such executables on your box - those, as far as I know, come with Windows. You'd need to google or ask a separate question on super user to solve such a problem. If both of them work, then you either have some sort of strange escaping options configured on your terminal/prompt (enable delayed expansion? I'm not sure here) or you have a typo in your command somewhere

Comment: `Cannot run program "FOR": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: @Hooli This is not a typical error to have inside a DOS Batch file. You may want to open a separate question.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham as this is an accepted answer, please consider adding points from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20637662/5243762 this answer as well

Comment: I had to remove %%P with %P or else was gettin this error: "%%P was unexpected at this time."

Comment: @saurabh.in I already stated this at the very bottom of my answer, so make sure to read the entire answer before commenting.

Answer (score 200):

Open command prompt and run the following commands

```
 C:\Users\username>netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:3000
   TCP    0.0.0.0:3000      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3116

C:\Users\username>taskkill /F /PID 3116
```

, here 3116 is the process ID

Comment: yeah that will differ everywhere

Comment: very useful ! Mind you I search for :3000 instead of 0.0:3000 because it could under 127.0.01 instead of 0.0.0.0

Comment: Thank you, great job killing an out of control webpack dev task :)

Comment: Or you may simply provide 
netstat -ano | findstr :9797

taskkill /PID typeyourPIDhere /F

Here 9797 is the port number, iI frequently  use this command to kill the misbehaving/hanged server.

Answer (score 58):

To find specific process on command line use below command here 8080 is port used by process

```
netstat -ano | findstr 8080
```

to kill process use below command here 21424 is process id

```
taskkill /pid 21424 /F
```

Comment: @EralpB Enjoy :)

Answer (score 23):

Using Merlyn's solution caused other applications to be killed like firefox.
These processes were using the same port, but not as a listener:

eg:

```
netstat -a -n -o | findstr :8085
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8085           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6568
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49616        127.0.0.1:8085         TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49618        127.0.0.1:8085         TIME_WAIT       0
```

Therefore, can excluded these by adding "LISTENING" to the findstr as follows:

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :8085.*LISTENING') DO TaskKill.exe /PID %%P
```

Comment: I got `%%P was unexpected at this time.`  Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 19):

To list all the process running on port 8080 do the following.

> netstat -ano | find "8080"

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       10612

TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       10612
```

Then to kill the process run the following command

> taskkill /F /PID 10612

Answer (score 16):

Thank you all, just to add that some process wont close unless the /F force switch is also send with TaskKill.
Also with /T switch, all secondary threads of the process will be closed.

> ```
> C:\>FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^|
>  findstr :2002') DO TaskKill.exe /PID %P /T /F
> ```

For services it will be necessary to get the name of the service and execute:

> sc stop ServiceName

Comment: Works fine on windows 10 !

Answer (score 7):

Created a bat file with the below contents, it accepts the input for port number

```
@ECHO ON
set /p portid=Enter the Port to be killed: 
echo %portid%                                                                              
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%T IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr %portid% ') DO (
SET /A ProcessId=%%T) &GOTO SkipLine                                                   
:SkipLine                                                                              
echo ProcessId to kill = %ProcessId%
taskkill /f /pid %ProcessId%
PAUSE
```

Finally click "Enter" to exit.

Comment: @TusharPandey This is windows tagged  question , so it is a windows script, not shell script

Answer (score 2):

Just for completion:

I wanted to kill all processes connected to a specific port but not the process listening

the command (in cmd shell) for the port 9001 is:

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %P IN ('netstat -ano ^| findstr -rc:":9001[ ]*ESTA"') DO TaskKill /F /PID %P
```

**findstr**:

- r is for expressions and c for exact chain to match.
- [ ]* is for matching spaces

**netstat**:

- a -> all
- n -> don't resolve (faster)
- o -> pid

It works because netstat prints out the source port then destination port and then ESTABLISHED

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Merlyn's response, but this one handles these cases as well:

- The port number is actually a left substring of another longer port
  number that you're not looking for.  You want to search for an
  **exact** port number so that you do not kill a random, innocent process!
- The script code needs to be able to run more than once and be correct each time, not showing older, incorrect
  answers.

Here it is:

```
set serverPid=
for /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%P in ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr /E :8080 ') do set serverPid=%%P
if not "%serverPid%" == "" (
  taskkill /PID %serverPid%
) else (
  rem echo Server is not running.
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to kill the process that's listening on port 8080, you could use PowerShell. Just combine [`Get-NetTCPConnection`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826153.aspx) cmdlet with [`Stop-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849781.aspx).

Tested and should work with PowerShell 5 on Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016. However, I guess that it should also work on older Windows versions that have PowerShell 5 installed.

Here is an example:

```
PS C:\> Stop-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 8080).OwningProcess

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform the Stop-Process operation on the following item: MyTestServer(9408)?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Go to `conf` folder of your **apache tomcat** server. In my case,its `apache-tomcat-7.0.61\conf` as I am using apache-tomcat-7.0.61
2. Open `server.xml` and change the port number from 8080 to any other port as your wish. For example:8081,8082,8087 etc
3. Now go to `bin` folder and run `shutdown.bat`
4. Now restart the server through eclipse.

Now your project will work without any interruption.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a Powershell Script:

```
function Search-And-Destroy
{
    param ( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$port )
    $lines = netstat -a -o -n | findstr $port
    $ports = @()

    ForEach($line In $lines)
    {
        $res = $($lines -split '\s+')
        $ports += $res[5]
    }

    $ports = $ports | select -uniq

    ForEach($port In $ports)
    {
        echo $(taskkill /F /PID $port)
    }
}
```

This function basically does what the above functions do, but it is in the Powershell scripting format so you can add it to your Powershell profile. To find your profile's location go to powershell and type `echo $profile`

Comment: This is not really a PowerShell script, but a PowerShell-based wrapper around `netstat` tool.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this into command line

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %P IN ('netstat -ano ^| find "LISTENING" ^| find ":8080 "') DO (TASKKILL /PID %P)
```

If you want to use it in a batch pu `%%P` instead of `%P`

Comment: This is dependent on the language of the OS, any way to make it work for all languages?

Comment: @Jakob This can only be run in cmd terminal in Windows, also only in .cmd or .bat files

Comment: Yes, but only in english language, since otherwise "LISTENING" will be translated to the language of the OS.

Comment: @Jakob I am not aware that `netstat` tool is translated to other languages