# Terminating mvn spring-boot:run doesn't stop tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I can successfully start spring-boot with `mvn spring-boot`, the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-manual-cli-installation) mentions to gracefully exit the application hit `ctrl-c`.

```
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? Y
```

The maven process does terminate but Tomcat is still running and I can still hit the web-page. When I try to start spring-boot again it fails to start Tomcat because the port is in use.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::  (v1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)

2014-05-02 12:13:57.666  INFO 6568 --- [           main] Example                                  : Starting Example on challenger with PID 6568 (E:\workspace\SpringBoot\target\cla
sses started by steven in E:\workspace\SpringBoot)
2014-05-02 12:13:57.707  INFO 6568 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWeb
ApplicationContext@11ecab7c: startup date [Fri May 02 12:13:57 EDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-05-02 12:13:58.097  INFO 6568 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean
: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfi
gure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class pat
h resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; laz
yInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAuto
ConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfig
ure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2014-05-02 12:13:58.682  INFO 6568 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Server initialized with port: 8080
2014-05-02 12:13:58.892  INFO 6568 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2014-05-02 12:13:58.892  INFO 6568 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.53
2014-05-02 12:13:58.981  INFO 6568 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2014-05-02 12:13:58.981  INFO 6568 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1277 ms
2014-05-02 12:13:59.453  INFO 6568 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2014-05-02 12:13:59.455  INFO 6568 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2014-05-02 12:13:59.570 ERROR 6568 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:344)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:336)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:199)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:473)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:647)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:449)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1007)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:459)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:79)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:270)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:680)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:930)
        at Example.main(Example.java:16)

2014-05-02 12:13:59.571 ERROR 6568 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol-
8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol-8080]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:459)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:79)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:270)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:680)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:930)
        at Example.main(Example.java:16)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1014)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:344)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:336)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:199)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:473)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:647)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:449)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1007)
        ... 19 common frames omitted

2014-05-02 12:13:59.572  INFO 6568 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2014-05-02 12:13:59.580  INFO 6568 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/E:/workspace/SpringBoot/src/m
ain/resources, file:/E:/workspace/SpringBoot/src/main/resources, file:/E:/workspace/SpringBoot/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring
-boot-starter-web/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-web-1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.1.0.BUI
LD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-1.1.0.BUILD-SNA
PSHOT.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar, file:/C:
/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.
m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.7/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2
/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.7/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.7/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/st
even/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.2/logback-core-1.1.2.jar, f
ile:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.13/snakeyaml-1.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.1.0.BUILD
-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.53/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.53.jar, f
ile:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/7.0.53/tomcat-embed-el-7.0.53.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-e
mbed-logging-juli/7.0.53/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.53.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.3.3/jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar, fi
le:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.3.0/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/co
re/jackson-core/2.3.3/jackson-core-2.3.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/
.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file
:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-cont
ext/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users
/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4
.0.3.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedde
d.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:135)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:680)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
[INFO] Total time: 4.653 s
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:930)
        at Example.main(Example.java:16)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-02T12:13:59-05:00
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:106)
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/232M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:270)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:102)
        ... 12 more
```

To proceed I have to manually terminate the running process. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: see my answer [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553018/spring-boot-tomcat-termination/25850563#25850563

Comment: Just simply run your project as a Java Application. Spring boot makes your jar an executable one. In Eclipse: Run As > Java Application

Comment: Because it can't. 

Stop a spring application that has been started by the "start" goal. 

see here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/stop-mojo.html

Answer (score 101):

It still happens to me on version 1.1.9 running on windows 7.

So after hitting Ctrl C. 
The fastest way to kill the background java will be .

Find the java PID

```
     c:\>netstat -ano | find "8080"
     TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1196
     TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       1196
     c:\>taskkill /F /PID 1196
     SUCCESS: The process with PID 1196 has been terminated.
```

I am  assuming in the example above that you are running on http port 8080

For Mac Users:

```
     $lsof -i :8080
     COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
     java    SOME_PID user  417u  IPv6 0xa4b3be242c249a27      0t0  TCP *:name (LISTEN)
     kill -9 SOME_PID
```

Comment: If you get an `Access Denied` message when running `taskkill` make sure you are running cmd in Administrator mode

Comment: @gudthing Nice. I got 'Access Denied', then I run cmd in Admin mode, it works. I want to know if I kill the task (A) which uses that port, will this cause issue when this task (A) run later?

Answer (score 26):

Here is what I do on Mac:

```
kill `lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP | grep 8080 | tr -s " " "\n" | sed -n 2p`
```

It finds the PID using 8080 and kills it.

Comment: Fow windows - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204003/kill-a-process-by-looking-up-the-port-being-used-by-it-from-a-bat

Comment: @Buminda that is if your application server runs not as a background process which is often the case

Answer (score 6):

Edit:
in ubuntu, use the command:

```
fuser -k 8080/tcp
```

to kill the process. I'm using spring-boot 1.3.0-Build-snapshot and the problem still persist. My SO is Ubuntu and the problem occurs either running from Eclipse or from the console. The discussion about this issue is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/773). This seems to be an issue with spring-boot libraries, at least concerning tomcat libraries. I'm also in the line for the this fix. Unfortunately this is the price we pay for trying to use cutting edge technologies until they get matured.

Comment: Perhaps this should be a comment instead?

Comment: This is actually the best solution

Answer (score 5):

For those using Eclipse, this is by far the best answer:

Open "run configurations", edit the maven launch you defined for your project, and under the "JRE" tab, add **-Dfork=false** to the VM arguments text area.

*Then when you hit the red stop button, the tomcat server will stop and your ports will be released.*

[Answer comes from a post here on Github by jordihs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1239)

Answer (score 3):

In IDEA you have to **Stop process** before **Run** it again. That command will shut down embedded Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

That only happens in Windows. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/773

Update: should be fixed now.

Comment: I'm at `1.1.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` and it is still present. What do you mean by "should be fixed"?

Comment: I mean that issue was fixed (if you run from the cmd window in windows you can stop the build and the app with CTRL-C). If you are using Cygwin you might find that it is still a problem, but Cygwin is unique and I'm not sure it's possible to fix there.

Comment: Still a problem when running out of Eclipse

Comment: Running what out of eclipse? What did you do exactly?

Comment: Right click on project -> Run as -> Maven build.  In goals put "spring-boot:run"  Run the app.  Now terminate it ( by the usual red stop button in the console view). Spring-boot process remains running.

Comment: I suggest you don't run Maven from inside Eclipse then. Just right click on the main class and Run As -> Java Application (or get STS and right click on project Run As -> Spring Boot Application).

Comment: @DaveSyer Thanks for that bit about Cygwin. I can confirm that this is still is a problem in Cygwin.

Comment: It always will be if you fork a process in Cygwin. The latest Boot releases 1.2.0 and up don't fork by default, but they have to fork if you are adding an agent.

Comment: Under Mac: same issue as described by @dancarter. Had to manually kill the process ('ps -ef | grep javaagent').

Comment: It works for other people on a UN*X system (including Mac). Please open an issue in github if this isn't the case for you - make sure you are using the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

I know i am too late to answer but may be some one get help with this. STS users can use the `Relaunch` button rather than `Run` to ensure that any existing instance is closed.
For Reference : 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is correct that when you do a maven install with spring-boot-run and after the application is stopped, tomcat port still listens.

I am attaching a screenshot for those who faced this problem port/address already in use.
What you have to do is before running the spring boot application again,just go to your windows Task  manager and end the Process named "Java(TM) Platform SE binary" and run your boot application your port would be free of the process and you wont get the issue again.(You don't have to do this after you run your application for the [image]first time )
It worked miracle for me. Hope it helps Good day

Answer (score 1):

I fall in the same issue, but there is a much better and simple way to run your Spring boot app that does not have this problem.

Run As -> Java Application

Update: 
Furthermore, if you use Spring STS (available for VS Code, IntelliJ, Eclipse...) you have the chance to manage your application from the Boot Dashboard. It's really useful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem when running spring boot app from netbeans 8.1 on Mac. The java process was not terminated when I hit red square button in netbeans so when I relaunched the app I always get "bind exception, adress already in use" thing. This is known bug.

The solution was to
[add spring-boot:run](https://bugzilla-attachments-241321.netbeans.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=151222) command to run goals of project...

...and also if you get "*No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups*" you might need to add this to dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem running SpringBoot application in eclipse on Mac. I manually had to find all the PID's using 8080 and kill them. But, fortunately, I realized that we can kill that tomcat instance right from the eclipse "console" view, by hitting the stop(Red square icon) button and run the spring boot application again.

Comment: This only works if you add the fork=false in the VM arguments. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cause a shutdown by calling 
`curl -v -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8091/shutdown` provided you configured spring-boot properly.

To support this you will have to update your application properties. This is partially described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26563344/58794 .

updating application.yml by adding:

```
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
endpoints:
  shutdown:
    enabled: true
```

or updating application.properties by adding:

```
management.security.enabled=false
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
```

Once called

```
$ curl -v -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8091/shutdown
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x600057990; line 1423 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x600057990; line 1475 (connection #0)
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8091 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x600057990; line 1592 (connection #0)
* Marked for [keep alive]: HTTP default
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x600057990; line 1610 (connection #0)
> POST /shutdown HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8091
> User-Agent: curl/7.56.1
> Accept: */*
>
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x600057990; line 1689 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x600057990; line 1814 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x600057990; line 1824 (connection #0)
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 200
< X-Application-Context: application:h2:8091
< Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Fri, 22 Dec 2017 07:01:04 GMT
<
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x600057990; line 1993 (connection #0)
* multi_done
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
* Expire cleared
{"message":"Shutting down, bye..."}
```

the container will shutdown

```
o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

but if you launched from `mvn spring-boot:run` you will likely get a:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 35.613 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-22T02:01:05-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/577M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.7.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project PROJECTNAME: Could not exec java: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
```

If you do not have `management.security.enabled=false` you may be presented with the following error:

```
$ curl -v -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8091/shutdown
> POST /shutdown HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8091
> User-Agent: curl/7.56.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 401
< X-Application-Context: application:h2:8091
< Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Fri, 22 Dec 2017 06:56:19 GMT
<
{"timestamp":1513925779265,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource.","path":"/shutdown"}
```

If you do not have `endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true` you will see:

```
$ curl -v -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8091/shutdown
> POST /shutdown HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8091
> User-Agent: curl/7.56.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404
< X-Application-Context: application:h2:8091
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Fri, 22 Dec 2017 06:58:52 GMT
<
{"timestamp":1513925932345,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/shutdown"}
```

If you try a GET instead of POST this error will be presented:

```
$ curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8091/shutdown
> GET /shutdown HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8091
> User-Agent: curl/7.56.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 405
< X-Application-Context: application:h2:8091
< Allow: POST
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Fri, 22 Dec 2017 06:54:12 GMT
<
{"timestamp":1513925652827,"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'GET' not supported","path":"/shutdown"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me with Spring Boot v1.x und works now, with v2.x:

```
hangingJavaProcessToStop=`jps | grep Application | awk '{print $1}'`
echo "hangingJavaProcessToStop: $hangingJavaProcessToStop"
kill -9 $hangingJavaProcessToStop
```

This way you can kill specifically Spring Boot's `Application` Java process instead of killing all Java processes at once. I assume if your Spring Boot "Application" (`main` method containing class) is called differently, you must use its name instead of `Application`.

I am running the snippet above, on my **Windows** machine using **WSL/Debian**. I am not using PowerShell or Windows'command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NetBeans you can stop the server or process by clicking on the cross icon in the bottom right corner where it says Run (Project name).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Powershell, put the following code in a file ending with '.ps1'

`$processes = (get-NetTCPConnection| ? {$_.LocalPort -eq "8080"}).OwningProcess
foreach ($process in $processes) {Get-Process -PID $process | Stop-Process -Force}`

Answer (score 0):

We can kill that tomcat instance right from the eclipse `console` view, by hitting the stop (Red square icon) button and Red button beside the run icon, run the spring boot application again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Windows 10, wenn I was running `mvn spring-boot:run` in a Cygwin Terminal. I wasn't even able to find the Tomcat process in Cygwin using `ps -ef`; I had to search for the process in PowerShell using `netstat -ao`.

Using `mvn spring-boot:run` in PowerShell is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on Mac OS recently, it seems this happened after upgrade my Mac OS version.

Use IntelliJ IDEA as IDE and install a spring boot, running process cannot be stopped as the port is still opened. I must use `lsof -i:<running port>` and `kill -9 <PID>` to kill the process manually every time, annoying!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the case of eclipse::
If getting this error, You con stop it on eclipse, no need to kiling from Task Manager, Please refer SS, Here all running survices present, select one and stop them.
[SS for error on eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muggj.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved in Spring boot 3.0.0 (To be released on 24th Nov 2022).

Issue link : [Bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32607)
Release notes : [Release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v3.0.0-RC1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Maven and this killed the SpringApplication process for me.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <exec executable="bash">
                                <arg value="-c"/>
                                <arg value="ps ax | awk '/[s]pring/ { print $1 }' | xargs kill"/>
                            </exec>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score -3):

Type the following commands in order.

```
$ ps -ef | grep -i java
$ kill -9 3361
```

Comment: everyone will have different PID and not 3361.

Comment: Helped. Thanks. BTW: I was able to modify the PID. :-)