# spring boot tomcat termination

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have exactly the same issue like that one:  [Terminating mvn spring-boot:run doesn't stop tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432651/terminating-mvn-spring-bootrun-doesnt-stop-tomcat)

The answer there says that it only happens on Windows but it's not actually true. I'm running spring boot on OSX with Intellij and when I stop the spring boot application the embedded tomcat is still running. The is the simple sample app from spring boot tutorial. Any solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Terminating mvn spring-boot:run doesn't stop tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432651/terminating-mvn-spring-bootrun-doesnt-stop-tomcat)

Comment: The answer to the duplicate also says that it's a known issue that was fixed in 1.1.0 snapshots. Did you try that?

Comment: I'm at 1.1.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and it still happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have met the same issue and as result I had to review all solutions on this page and related one. No one is good for me. That is why I have made small research and it is appeared that problems with captured TCP port happen just because neither Gradle nor mvn knows nothing about child manipulation with TCP port.

So instead of killing process just use command:

```
$ gradlew –stop
```

(I hope the same exists for `mvn`)

This command gracefully closes daemons started by Gradle and frees captured by Tomcat ports.

Answer (score 7):

i have exactly the same issue within intellij on MAC (spring boot 1.1.6.RELEASE).

i worked around it by using spring boot actuator which offers a rest endpoint (Post) to shutdown the app:

```
localhost:port/shutdown
```

this can be called by commandline: e.g. `curl -X POST localhost:port/shutdown`

to enable spring boot actuator add the following compile dep:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator
```

i created a gradle task bootStop which does run this cmd for me.
you could do the same in maven or
you can just call it from cmd line (also trough the intellij terminal)

Especially if you want to use debugging, you should wrap the curl cmd given above in a gradle/maven task.

See working example (gradle) [here](https://github.com/dasAnderl/SpringBootPrimefacesGradle/blob/master/build.gradle)

Comment: I just use bootRun task from command line instead of IDE. So in my case I just run: `./gradlew bootRun`. And when I want to stop the server I just stop the build script by pressing ctrl+C

Comment: this might be fine if you dont want any debugging features of your ide. if you want to use them you have to call the tasks through the ide, so i think my approach is better.

Comment: if I want to debug I just run the project as a plain java application from IDE

Comment: you can also attach the debugger "remotely" (general instructions here: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html) by running in debug mode easily done with the Maven Boot plugin as described here: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is a maven example for spring boot actuator to configure HTTP endpoint to shutdown a spring boot web app:

1.Maven Pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2.application.properties:

```
#No auth  protected 
endpoints.shutdown.sensitive=false

#Enable shutdown endpoint
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
```

All endpoints are listed [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-endpoints):

3.Send a post method to shutdown the app:

```
curl -X POST localhost:port/shutdown
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25850563/4905045) answer, this property is deprecated now, so replace it with:

```
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is to create a "Spring Boot" configuration and use that to start your app instead of the "Gradle" configuration.  The "Spring Boot" configuration does not experience this issue.