# Spring integration: Shutdown application when the handling of files is completed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

How to create automatic shutdown in spring integration after finish all process for all files?

My application download undefined number of files and process all files sequentially, the flow is like this:

```
file:inbound-channel-adapter --> Transformer --> Splitter -->
http-outbound-gateway --> int:aggregator --> mail:outbound-channel-adapter.
```

At the End, i should shutdown my app.

How to know that all files are processed?
Anyone has an experience about it ?

Thanks

Comment: Just don't include the spring-web starter module. This way the application will be a standard java app and will end as soon as the job is ended.

Comment: I like to exit the app completely

Comment: That's a normal Java program, the application will end and exit.

Comment: I  ask how trigger the app that the processing is completed not how to exit the application

Answer (score 1):

In you case you need to track your inbound directory.
You have to add another step to your flow (probably to track the last file).
I would suggest an ETL technique: Read file descriptions then process them.

When it will be processed you can send event to shutdown the app.

Spring boot application can be stopped by using `ConfigurableApplicationContext`:

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = app.run(args);
context.close();
```

Also there is another way using Spring Actuator `shutdown` endpoint:
See [How to shutdown a Spring Boot Application in a correct way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547532/how-to-shutdown-a-spring-boot-application-in-a-correct-way)

[Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready)