# Spring graceful shutdown - REQUEST METHOD POST NOT SUPPORTED

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to use the Spring `endpoints` to gracefully shut down my application but I'm getting an error:

```
2016-08-09 13:46:54.606  WARN 13315 --- [nio-8090-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Handler execution resulted in exception: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547532/how-to-shutdown-a-spring-boot-application-in-a-correct-way) guide and I've set my `application.properties` to have `endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true` and also `endpoints.shutdown.sensitive=false`. I've also included `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")` in my build.gradle.

When I send the CURL request: `curl -X POST https://localhost:8090/shutdown -k`
I get the following response from the server:

```
{"timestamp":1470747537792,"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/shutdown"}
```

Am I doing anything incorrectly? Is there anything that I may be missing? I have CSRF enabled throughout the app so it's not an option to disable that for my application.

Comment: What happens if you don't use POST?

Comment: `{"timestamp":1470748694304,"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'GET' not supported","path":"/shutdown"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As david suggested, CSRF is required because it's globally required for all `POST` requests by Spring. So The only way I could think of bypassing it is by disabling the CSRF for the `/shutdown` endpoint.

In my `SecurityConfig` I set:

```
http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/shutdown");
```

This would disable the csrf protection **only** for the `/shutdown` url whilst keeping it active for the rest of the application.

Note: This facility was added in Spring 4.

Answer (score 3):

You need to send a CSRF token either as a header or a parameter or something. Your example:

```
curl -X POST https://localhost:8090/shutdown -k
```

does not include a CSRF token so of course Spring will reject it. That is indeed the whole point of the CSRF filter. You will need to decide whether it is appropriate to exclude the `/shutdown` uri from that filter or whether you want to require a token/nonce to be present.

Comment: I understand that the CSRF is required but how can I send a CSRF token to the `/shutdown` URI? Is there a way to generate a token and send that as a parameter? It's not a request mapping that I'm defining as it's predefined in Spring so I'm confused on how to provide headers for the request.

Answer (score 1):

I'am using Springboot-1.5.3-RELEASE, use http method **POST** (not GET)。 It works.

Answer (score 1):

If you use spring-boot-starter-actuator:

I had the same issue and added following text into the application.properties file in the src/main/resources folder.

```
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,shutdown
```

Rebuild the application, run it and send the request ( for example: localhost:8080/actuator/shutdown )