# How to configure Tomcat shutdown port in Spring Boot?

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

Looking for way how to configure shutdown port in Spring boot app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can configure the spring-boot application this way, since it's very relative to the underlying container and this tomcat specific property is not added to the [common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) you are allowed to use.

Another solution is to use spring boot actuator endpoint instead. It has a [`shutdown`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) endpoint for such a tasks. All you need is to use spring-actuator and enable this endpoint, since it's disabled by default.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547532/how-to-shutdown-a-spring-boot-application-in-a-correct-way) is yet another SO question, you may find useful though it's unanswered, about the way to shutdown spring boot application.