# Spring Boot Maven plugin - spring-boot:run and graceful shutdown

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I can run a Spring Boot application with a following Maven command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

but I don't know how to do a  graceful shutdown of application which was started in a such way. Please advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to shutdown a Spring Boot Application in a correct way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547532/how-to-shutdown-a-spring-boot-application-in-a-correct-way)

Comment: Have you tried with Ctrl-c as per the doc here http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-run ? If so, did you see any issues ?

Comment: manual Ctrl-c works fine but I want to automate this process and use it from my scripts

Comment: @alexanoid, Refer this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547532/how-to-shutdown-a-spring-boot-application-in-a-correct-way/34875139#34875139 it has couple of answers which might be helpful,

Comment: If you want to automate don't use `mvn spring-boot:run` use an executable jar as explained in the reference guide.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To gracefully exit your application simply hit `ctrl-c` in your terminal.

Or you can use `mvn spring-boot:start` to start you app in background and `mvn spring-boot:stop` to shutdown gracefuly.

Comment: manual Ctrl-c works fine but I want to automate this process and use it from my scripts

Comment: So you should use 'mvn spring-boot:start' to start you app in background and 'mvn spring-boot:stop' to shutdown gracefully.