# How to make Spring Boot v2.0.0.M7 Actuator's shutdown work?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I created hello world Spring Boot v2.0.0.M7 app, added actuator, enabled shutdown and it isn't working.

application.properties

```
server.port=8082
endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
endpoint.shutdown.sensitive=false
```

health works fine

[image]

but not the shutdown

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you have to POST to the shutdown endpoint. Likely a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700355/using-the-spring-boot-actuator-to-shutdown-a-rest-server-safely

Comment: @Marged Does the official documentation mentioned this? How would I suppose to know it? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

Comment: Like Andy confirmed: it is stated in the docs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Endpoints have changed quite a bit in Spring Boot 2.0 and, as a result, your configuration is out of date. You need to enable the endpoint and also expose it over HTTP:

```
management.endpoints.web.expose=*
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
```

As already noted in the comments, and described in the [Actuator HTTP API documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/actuator-api/html/#shutdown), you also need to make a `POST` request so accessing the endpoint in your browser won't work. You can use something like `curl` on the command line instead:

```
$ curl -X POST localhost:8080/actuator/shutdown
```

You can learn more about changes in Spring Boot 2.0 by reading the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes).

Comment: Thank you! I missed the fact that besides exposing the endpoint, one has to explicitly enable it, too! Otherwise one has a warning in the log (but I haven't paid enough attention to it and thus could not determine what I had been missing).

Comment: The documentation of Spring Boot is confusing: it says, to enable 'shutdown' endpoint one should only add `management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true` to the application.properties.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.0/reference/htmlsingle/#using

Comment: Spring Boot makes a distinction between an endpoint being enabled and it being exposed through JMX or HTTP. This is [described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.0/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.endpoints). Setting `management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true` is sufficient to enable the endpoint. For security reasons, enabled endpoints are only exposed over JMX by default. If you want it to be accessible over HTTP, you need to [configure web exposure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.0/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.endpoints.exposing).

Answer (score 10):

spring boot version : 2.0.1.RELEASE

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

application.properties

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=shutdown
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
```

then, try

```
$ curl -X POST localhost:8080/actuator/shutdown
```

Comment: Thank you for additional info about the need of setting `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=shutdown`.

The documentation of Spring Boot is confusing: it says, to enable 'shutdown' endpoint one should only add `management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true` to the application.properties.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.0/reference/htmlsingle/#using

Answer (score 6):

spring-boot 2.0 default 
`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info, health`,
 
change to 
`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info, health, shutdown`