# Spring Boot Actuator 2.0.0 ShutDown endpoint returns error 415 when invoked with POST request

Tags: powershell, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am using `spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.0.0.RELEASE` with the following enabled:

```
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=shutdown
management.security.basic.enabled=false
```

From PowerShell command, I invoked the `shutdown` endpoint with:

```
$endpointUrl = "http://localhost:8200/actuator/shutdown"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $endPointUrl -Method POST
```

and I got:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (415).
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $endPointUrl -Method POST
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

In my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, I have:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .csrf()
    .disable();
```

What's wrong with my Web request call?

Comment: Error 415 is 'Unsupported media type'. I think no wonder because you are doing a POST without a body

Comment: @Theo I tried with a body and got the same `415`. The actuator endpoint `shutdown` can only be invoked with a POST. I don't think it expects any params

Comment: I can only find cUrl commands where indeed a POST is used, but also wilt an `-X` argument. However, I also found this answer on StackOverflow which might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192765/how-to-make-spring-boot-v2-0-0-m7-actuators-shutdown-work

Comment: @Theo I tried that and it actually works in a Linux environment... But here on Windows Command Line, it's got this error... Also, this only happens in version `2.0.0+`, previously I used `1.5+` in another project, I could shut down fine with the PowerShell script above

Comment: hummmm.. I don't think i can help you there then. The `-X` seems to alter the behavior of the curl command from POST to something else. The `-i` tells it to include the header in the output, so in Powershell you maybe need to do something like `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $endPointUrl -Method Head` instead??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default ContentType in `Invoke-WebRequest` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6

> -ContentType
>   Specifies the content type of the web request. If this parameter is omitted and the request method is POST, Invoke-WebRequest sets the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Otherwise, the content type is not specified in the call.

I tried in Postman and `shutdown` endpoint works with `application/json` or without ContentType header at all (didn't find this in Spring documentation). But looks like there might be some issues with setting this header to `application/json` (https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3131)
So probably just try to set `-ContentType 'application/json' -Body "null"`. I don't have Windows machine to try.

Comment: Hey, adding `-ContentType 'application/json'` works! It doesn't need `-Body "null"`. Thanks so much