# Spring Boot closes hibernate session on shutdown - before @Async methods are finished

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with a spring boot application that closes the EntityManager/session on shutdown before `@Async` tasks (that use the EntityManager) are finished.

There are 2 classes relevant for this problem:

**Scheduler**

The scheduled method reserves a limited number of jobs and calls an `@Async` method on `XYJobProcessor` that does the actual work.

```
@Component
public class XYJobProcessingTimer {

    private final XYJobService      xyJobService;
    private final XYJobProcessor    xyJobProcessor;

    //constructor skipped

    @Scheduled(initialDelayString = "${initial_delay}", fixedDelayString = "${delay}")
    public void performXYJobProcessing() {
        final String ticket = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        final int reservedJobs = xyJobService.findAndReserveReadyXYJobs(ticket);

        if (reservedJobs > 0) {
            final Collection<XYJob> xyJobs = xyJobService.readReservedJobs(ticket);
            xyJobProcessor.process(xyJobs);
        }
    }

}
```

**Async Processor**

The @Async annotated method calls the service that accesses the EntityManager.

```
@Service
public class XYJobProcessor {

    private final XYJobService  xyJobService;

    // constructor skipped

    @Async("xyJobProcessorExecutor")
    public void process(final Collection<XYJob> jobs) {
        // This service uses the EntityManager and takes some time depending o job count.
        xyJobService.createXYJobsAndDelete(jobs);
    }

}
```

**Configuration**

The configuration of the `Executor` that runs the `@Async` tasks. The created Threads are non-daemon.

```
@Configuration
public class AsyncExecutorConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "xyJobProcessorExecutor")
    public Executor xyJobProcessorExecutor() {
        final SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor executor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        executor.setConcurrencyLimit(10);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Hasselhoff-");
        return executor;
    }

}
```

**The Problem**

When I shut down the application, spring closes the EntityManager Session immediately - before all `@Async` tasks have finished. This leads to the following Exception:

```
2017-08-31 16:10:54.212 ERROR 12663 --- [Hasselhoff-12] .a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler : Unexpected error occurred invoking async method 'public void de.xy.services.XYJobProcessor.process(java.util.Collection)'.org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Session is closed!; nested exception is org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
        at de.xy.services.XYJobService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6b9cb1ae.createXYJobsAndDelete(<generated>)
        at de.xy.services.XYJobProcessor.process(XYJobProcessor.java:24)
        at de.xy.services.XYJobProcessor$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ccc40c8f.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:268)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getPersistenceContext(SessionImpl.java:2088)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:340)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
        ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Is there a way to make Spring wait for `@Async` executions to finish before it closes the EntityManager? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Maybe this thread could help: [how-to-shutdown-a-spring-boot-application-in-a-correct-way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547532/how-to-shutdown-a-spring-boot-application-in-a-correct-way)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I am already shutting down the application gracefully. The problem is that spring closes the EntityManager before (still running) @Async methods have finished their work, resulting in the exception.

Comment: Use a different executor like the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and set the `waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` property to `true`.

Comment: Is this thread of any help ?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4657

Comment: @M.Deinum I already tried the {ThreadPoolTaskExecutor}, but it behaves the same as the {SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor} when {waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown} is set to {true}. But: Because of your comment, I re-checked other available settings on the {ThreadPoolTaskExecutor} and found the exact solution for my problem. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. (I will add an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @M.Deinum, I found out how to avoid the problem:

Using a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` (instead of `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`) and setting it's `awaitTerminationSeconds` property in combination with `waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` set to `true` fixes my issue.

From the JavaDoc of `setAwaitTerminationSeconds`:

> Set the maximum number of seconds that this executor is supposed to
>   block on shutdown in order to wait for remaining tasks to complete
>   their execution before the rest of the container continues to shut
>   down. This is particularly useful if your remaining tasks are likely
>   to need access to other resources that are also managed by the
>   container.

This is the exact description and solution for my problem.