# configuring HTTP endpoint to shutdown a spring boot web application

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, server, tomcat7, application-shutdown

I have a Spring boot application running. Referring https://stackoverflow.com/a/36275797/6038386 to gracefully shut down the server, I included all changes in my pom.xml and application.properties.

Problem is when I am running spring boot server on one terminal (It starts successfully as expected) and try to shut it down using command: `curl -X POST localhost:8000/shutdown` on another terminal, server still keeps running. It is not shutting down. On my local, I don't see any logs or exception when i hit this shutdown command.

**

> Can someone please help me to figure out, what is missing in my
>   configuration.

**

Note: When I tried to shut down the server using Jenkins job having same command (and running jenkins server had same pom and properties as my local), i got following exception: `{"timestamp":1515145896307,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError","message":"org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/ShutdownEndpoint$1","path":"/shutdown"}`

My pom.xml is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>AllergiesConditions</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Exclude Spring Boot's Default Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>AllergiesConditions</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

my application.properties includes following lines:

```
server.port=8000
endpoints.shutdown.sensitive=false
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
```

Comment: How do you resolve this problem?

Comment: @ArthurWu Please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48130656/6038386

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Actually it was a silly mistake. I was just copy pasting the stuff from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36275797/6038386 without actually understanding it.

I had included `server.contextPath=/AllergiesConditions` in my application.properties

So now command to shutdown would become: `curl -X POST localhost:8080/AllergiesConditions/shutdown`

Another mistake I did was that, I didn't post my full application.properties in question's description, so actually no one could help.

Answer (score 0):

With the 1.5 version of spring boot , i think there is no sure shutdown mechanism.

You can see check this link and follow how to properly shutdown with jmx or http,  https://github.com/corentin59/spring-boot-graceful-shutdown in your application.

good Luck

Comment: :No, actually I have another project with version 1.5.9 - and normal shutdown mechanism mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36275797/6038386 works fine there. Looks like there is something else going wrong in code here.