# How to set timeout for Spring Boot Stopping gracefully?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, shutdown

Is there any application property or configuration to set timeout. I think in some case I saw that if default timeout is crossed, Spring boot shuts down without waiting for process completion.
I don't see any [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

I am trying to stop like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44590117/3002336

Comment: What if you capture SIGQUIT signal and start your own timer before calling `System.exit()`?

Comment: Is that how, you would be doing it for stopping Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I dont see any properties in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html.

You might want to raise it as an issue in the git project, here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues