# Java Spring Boot, thread not shutting down

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a **spring boot** java application that I'm trying to make gracefully shutdown. I'm using the shutdown endpoint.

My application is receiving `WebSocket` connections. When there is no connection yet the application shutdown correctly, but as soon as the first connection happens the shutdown will get stuck because the thread created by the connection *is not affected by the graceful shutdown*.

The way I catch the shutdown of the application is with `ContextClosedEvent`

like this :

```
@Override
    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextClosedEvent event) {
        connector.pause();
        Executor executor = this.connector.getProtocolHandler().getExecutor();
        if (executor instanceof ThreadPoolExecutor) {
            try {
                ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) executor;

                threadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
                if (!threadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {

                    threadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow();

                    if (!threadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                        logger.error("Tomcat thread pool did not terminate");
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException  ex)  {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
```

*And my thread are created like this :*

```
private ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);

private void foo(String bar) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()

        ScheduledFuture<?> future = executorService.schedule(runnable, sessionTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        sessionFutures.put(sessionId, future);
    }
```

The thread that is created and that is not affected by threadPoolExecutor.shutdown() or .shutdownNow() is [image: Name and description of the thread]

My question is why this thread isn't shut down and how can I make it shutdown?

My hypothesis is that i don't associate the task I'm creating to the current executor that is running.

Comment: i know this does not answer your question, but here is an alternate method for shutdown, did you try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547532/how-to-shutdown-a-spring-boot-application-in-a-correct-way

Comment: Yes, I chose the shutdown endpoint because I can use it with the preStop hook of a Kubernetes deployment

Comment: When you create the threads, how is the behavior if you replace your own instance of `ScheduledExecutorService` with the [TaskScheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) from Spring?

Comment: Now yes and it isn't working either