Issues with H2 Database and Spring Data JPA - Records not Updating and Autogenerated IDs are not sequentially stored
Description:
I am encountering two separate issues with my Spring Boot application using H2 database and Spring Data JPA.
Problem Statement 1: Records Not Updating Properly
I have a Spring Boot application with three tables: A, B, and C. Tables A and B have only one record each, while table C has multiple records.
In table B, one record is updated every 10 minutes using JPA, but the fields of this record are not updating properly.
I have tested the same functionality using normal JDBC without Spring Data JPA, and it works correctly. This suggests a potential issue with H2 database or JPA integration.
Problem Statement 2: Autogenerated IDs Restarting
When I start the H2 database for the first time and make inserts, the autogenerated IDs increment correctly (e.g., 1, 2, 3, etc.). However, if I stop the Spring Boot application and restart it, the autogenerated IDs start from a position much higher than where they left off (e.g., 30 positions above).
Questions:
What could be causing the records in table B not to update properly when using Spring Data JPA?
How can I ensure that the autogenerated IDs in H2 database continue incrementing correctly even after restarting the Spring Boot application?
Additional Information:
I am using Spring Boot version 2.7.9 and more and H2 database with different versions like 2.x.x
I tried on different cloud servers.
Below are the method where I'm updating the record
public void fetchLogs() {
    try {

        CompletableFuture<Object> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            String startTime = "";
            long signinLogCount = 0;
            Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            Logenablermodel updateLogEnabler = logenablermodelDao.findAll().get(0);
            startTime = updateLogEnabler.getLastLog();
            String endTime = dateTimeFormatter4.format(LocalDateTime.now());
            endTime = endTime.concat("Z");
            String signInResponse = "sfsdf";
            Logenabler logenabler = logenablerDao.findById(1L).get();
            if (signInResponse != null) {
                updateingFieldByUsingJdbc(endTime,Field_Name);
            }
            
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

Below are the Entity class
@Table(name = "logenablermodel")
public class Logenablermodel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "lastLog")
    private String lastLog;
    
    @Column(name = "contenType")
    private String contenType;

// setters and getters

}

Here it is not updating the lastLog field.

"tried on different cloud servers", But why? 'Records not updating properly' it's very difficult for us to guess why it's happening. Does this answer your second problem?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64125581/with-spring-jpa-and-h2-database-the-id-isnt-consequent-after-app-restart

Could you please provide an example of JPA entity class that does not update properly and any custom configuration for the spring-data-jpa that your project has.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I add code as well in above, please check and let me know the possible solutions.
