# In maven project, how to create a file to launch and stop an executable batch jar file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

In a maven spring-boot batch application, i can launch the jar file using the command line : java -jar mayapp.jar
That's convenient for a developper, but a user needs a file to luanch the appl (jar), and anoter one to stop it. I created a file start.bat which contain the command line.
I need to create anoter one to stop the jar, but i don't found a solution.
This is the content of the build in pom.xml :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Question :**

- What is the solution to stop the executable jar when it is luanched ?
- Is this the best way to do ? or ther's better solution, for examble create a *.exe, and how ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I hope this helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547532/how-to-shutdown-a-spring-boot-application-in-a-correct-way

Comment: Thankou for your help @NagarajuChitimilla, i will try these solutions and say wich one work and i use.