# How does one shutdown embedded Tomcat in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, netbeans, spring-boot

I'm using NetBeans IDE and Maven with Spring Boot. Whenever I run my app more than once, I get this error:

> o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>
> java.net.BindException: Address already in use
>
> spring boot java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state

I'm assuming this means that Tomcat isn't getting shutdown. How can I properly shutdown the embedded Tomcat in Spring Boot (preferably from the IDE)?

Comment: Ideally when you stop the server from IDE, then it shuts down. If not, then your IDE failed to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a netbeans configuration that fixed my problem.  See this screenshot:  https://bugzilla-attachments-241321.netbeans.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=151222

Comment: and if you get "No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot'" error then here is my solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/37260567/4443323