# how to stop all ports in apache tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

While developing a web application using Apache Tomacat and Eclipse frequently I get this message

> Several ports (7354, 6544, 9999) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

I know that this ports are in use, but I don't if I stop all those servers also why get the same message. My question is - Is there any way to stop all ports at once in using Eclipse or Windows 7 ?

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204003/kill-a-process-by-looking-up-the-port-being-used-by-it-from-a-bat

Comment: possible duplicate of [Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat Server at localhost are already in use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064733/several-ports-8005-8080-8009-required-by-tomcat-server-at-localhost-are-alre)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `lsof` in combination with `awk`. do the following:

```
lsof -i :<portnumber> | awk '{print "kill -9 "$2}' | sh
```

if you want to know only the processId from the port, use:

```
lsof -i :<portnumber> | awk '{print $2}'
```

---

btw: i have this problem sometimes too. If you're using eclipse check in the debug view if there is still a thread of the tomcat running. if so, stop them :)
Otherwise restart eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the following?

```
ps -ef | grep <port number>
kill -9 <process id>
```

Comment: I think its should be ```kill -9 <pid>``` not ```kill -9 <port number>```

Comment: How does grepping `ps -ef` allow you to search by port number? I've never seen it include the port number. At least not on RHEL/CENTOS machines.