# Code 255 due to unexpected command

Tags: windows, cmd, teamcity

I'm trying to kill process on `6373` port (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204003/kill-a-process-by-looking-up-the-port-being-used-by-it-from-a-bat)) with following code:

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :6373') DO TaskKill.exe /F /PID %P
```

and this works if I run it from `cmd` on local machine...

But got

```
6373') was unexpected at this time.
Process exited with code 255
```

if I try to run it as build-step on `TeamCity` `Windows` agent

I tried `tokens=4` instead of `tokens=5` as well as `%%P` instead of `%P`, but got same result. Can anyone point on my mistake?

Comment: Have you run the script just on the command line on the build agent machine?

Comment: yes. I run it simply from `cmd`

Answer (score 1):

The code can be rewritten to remove the uncertainty of an unknown number of tokens.

Single line from console window:

```
@Set "PID=" & @(For /F "Tokens=*" %a In ('NetStat -a -n -o^|Find ":6373 "') Do @For %b In (%a) Do @Set PID=%b) & @If Defined PID TaskKill /F /PID %PID%
```

Batch file version:

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal
Set "PID="
For /F "Tokens=*" %%a In ('NetStat -a -n -o^|Find ":6373 "') Do (
    For %%b In (%%a) Do Set PID=%%b
)
If Defined PID TaskKill /F /PID %PID%
```