# How to stop jupyter server using anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I am using anaconda navigator to launch jupyter notebook server, But when I want to stop the server, I could not find a way to do it.

Because there is no terminal when I'm using anaconda navigator, I can't use **Ctrl +c** to stop the server.  And I am running on Windows.

Any help will be appreciated ^_^

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: sorry about i didn't  mention this , i using windows .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can click on the check box which appears when you close anaconda navigator.

[image: Refer Snapshot here]

If you have already closed the navigator, open `cmd` and type `jupyter-notebook list`.

Then you can kill the port using following commands:

```
netstat -o -n -a | findstr :3000
   TCP    0.0.0.0:3000      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3116

taskkill /F /PID 3116
```

Substitute findstr parameter with which ever port is running.
[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30703100/3959965) on how to kill a process in windows.

Comment: that's all i need, it works for me ,thank you very much .

Comment: Glad it helped. You can mark this as answer, so that it helps others as well.